# Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote when using $parse in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing

I'm trying to set a model value - with feet inch value (0'-0"). The model has been parsed using `$parse` in `angular` and is being set using:

```
var toBeUpdatedModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

scope.$apply(toBeUpdatedModel.assign(scope, convertedValue))
```

When I do this I'm getting an error:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 2-7 ['-0\"] in expression [-0'-0\"].
```

Is there a way we can set these values without hooking up additional watches or using escape and unescape?

Comment: try scaping the string before parsing it

Comment: i cannot escape since the value of this data is being shown in a text box

Comment: can i see how are you declaring your directive and how are you passing the value down? it seems ngModel already has the value you don't need to parse it